# No autocomplete/code completion on Remix?

Tags: solidity, remix

I was watching a tutorial on Youtube on Remix and he has autocomplete while typing code but I don't. Does anyone know how to enable it? This would help me code so much easier and I can't find solutions to this anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

For me helped just hitting a "settings" button at the left bottom side and enabling the "Enable code completion in editor." setting in general settings

Answer (score 0):

When i change the browser Chrome to Brave it fixing. I do not know why it is not working with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just reloaded Remix, and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Make sure your file is in the contracts folder. If it is not in the contracts folder it will not autocomplete.

Answer (score -1):

Check your license identifier, that worked for me in the chrome browser.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).