# Remix IDE has no autocomplete?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

I started learing about blockchain and coding with Solidity in Remix IDE. But my Remix has no autocompletion, i changed every web browers: Chrome, Edge, Brave, FF,... nothing worked. Anyone has solution for this?

Comment: This may solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/q/70588875/14264497

Comment: Thank you. I tried it all but nothing works. I think it missing some kinds of library

Comment: Auto complete worked for me in chrome. And my contract was in Contracts folder

Answer (score 0):

just go to settings and check " Enable code completion in editor "